# ANTLR recursive syntax matching

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following **grammar**

```
grammar Group;

script: statementList;

statementList: (statement NEWLINE+)*;


statement: titleStatement | groupStatement;

titleStatement
    : 'hello_world' WS+ ':' WS+ IDENTIFIER;

groupStatement
        :groupDefStatement
         (messageFlowStatementList | groupStatement)
         END
         ;

messageFlowStatementList: (messageFlowStatement NEWLINE+)*;

messageFlowStatement: processingStatement;



groupDefStatement : GROUP WS+ (NAME WS* EQ_SYMBOL WS* STRINGX WS* COMMA_SYMBOL WS*)?
                            PATH WS* EQ_SYMBOL WS* STRINGX WS*
                            (COMMA_SYMBOL WS* METHOD WS* EQ_SYMBOL WS* STRINGX WS*)? NEWLINE+;

processingStatement: PROCESS_MESSAGE LPAREN STRINGX COMMA_SYMBOL STRINGX RPAREN;
```

To match the following **script**,

```
hello_world : abc

group name="group", path="hello", method="POST"

group name="group", path="hello", method="POST"
process_message("aaa","bbb")
end

group name="group", path="hello", method="POST"
process_message("aaa","bbb")
end

end
```

**or**

```
hello_world : abc
group name="group", path="hello", method="POST"
process_message("aaa","bbb")
end
```

The 2nd one matches as expected, but the first one doesn't match.

In the first script, the 2nd inner group doesn't match under the parent group.

Instead it matches with the `statement`

[this is the tree view with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9vnh.png)

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

It's missing an 'end' after the first group. The second group is nested, but according to the rule `groupStatement`, they both need an end. A correct input for this, which should parse is:

```
hello_world : abc

group name="group", path="hello", method="POST"

group name="group", path="hello", method="POST"
process_message("aaa","bbb")
end
end

group name="group", path="hello", method="POST"
process_message("aaa","bbb")
end

end
```

If you want the original input to be correct, you can change the `groupStatement` rule to:

```
groupStatement
    : groupDefStatement messageFlowStatementList END
    | groupDefStatement groupStatement
    ;
```

Then it should parse correctly.